# Why the ConfigurationBuilder API does not create a Logger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am trying to create a log4j2 logger programmatically using the ConfigurationBuilder API in spring boot application.
But the code does not seem to work properly.

Below is the code snippet I am trying to achieve this:

```
    String loggerName = "testLogger";
    final ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    final LoggerComponentBuilder loggerComp = builder.newLogger(loggerName, Level.ALL).addAttribute("additivity",
            false);

    builder.add(loggerComp);

    LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    ctx.start();
    ctx.updateLoggers();
    System.out.println(ctx.hasLogger(loggerName));
```

I expected the logger to be created in the LoggerContext and test it using

`ctx.hasLogger(loggerName)`

It should return me true.But it returns false.

What could be the possible issue in the above code.

On some debugging I found that ctx.hasLogger goes in the loggerRegistry to find if the logger with the NAME provided as an argument exists there or not and It does not found it, so it returns false.
What I think is that the custom logger is never created so that is why ctx.hasLogger() returns false.

Also,I have not used explicitly any configuration file for log4j2. 
When the spring boot application runs it takes into account its own log4j2.xml which is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD">%xwEx</Property>
            <Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN">%5p</Property>
            <Property name="LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN">yyyy-MM-dd         
 HH:mm:ss.SSS
            </Property>
            <Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}}}{faint} %clr{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{%pid}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}</Property>
            <Property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN">%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} %pid --- [%t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}</Property>
            </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
                <PatternLayout pattern="${sys:CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}" />
            </Console>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="error" />
            <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="error" />
            <Logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="warn" />
            <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="warn"/>
            <Logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="warn" />
        <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="error" />
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="warn" />
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" level="warn"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: The line `builder.add(loggerComp);` only add "configuration" for logger, and does not actually create logger. `ctx.hasLogger(loggerName)` will return true after you call `ctx.getLogger(loggerName)`, where the logger is actually created using the configuration you add.

Comment: @samabcde : Yes, I agree that ctx.getLogger(loggerName) could work but is there any way i can verify that the logger created is using the configuration added.

Comment: I suppose the library should do the job correctly. If you really want to verify, call `getLevel()`, `isAddictive()` and other method from the logger instance created by `getLogger(loggerName)` to check if those properties match with the configuration.

Comment: @samabcde : thanks, these checks helped me to verify.But unfortunately they show mis-matching results like for above code, getLevel() -should return ALL, but I get INFO and for isAddictive() also it is the opposite.

Comment: When I add line `System.out.println(ctx.getLogger(loggerName).isAdditive())` and `System.out.println(ctx.getLogger(loggerName).isAdditive())` using your code in a main method, I saw *false* and *ALL*. Please provide a complete example for reproducing your problem.

Comment: @samabcde : You are correct, when I do check in a simple Test class it works fine as expected as you explained.
But the code I am running is in a Spring boot Application and I think that is creating some problem.
The thing can be replicated in the following git repo (Log4j2TestApplication.java) : https://github.com/raman699/log4j2-Test

Comment: I think the issue is while creating configuration, log4j2 takes into account log4j2.xml of spring boot because I have not provided it on my own.I have also updated the description of the question.

Comment: I would suggest running your spring boot app with -Dlog4j2.debug=true set. This will log all the times Log4j gets configured. With Spring Boot that will happen at least 3 times. If your configuration is not last then Spring Boot will reconfigure and override yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the solution of the issue I was facing.The issue was at the starting of the configuration.

Initially the LoggerContext starts with the default configuration found(of spring boot) i.e when we do `ctx.start()`.

But to make our configurations work, we need to start context with our configuration i.e 
modify the code as below:

`Configuration configuration = builder.build();
 ctx.start(configuration);`

After this `ctx.getLogger(loggerName)` works good enough to return a Logger with the specified configurations.
And you can verify it by calling `getLevel()` or `isAdditive()` on the returned logger to match your configs.

Thanks to @samabcde whose advice helped to reach to final solution.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's any way to configure this so LogManger.getLogger() returns the appropriate logger? This solution works for me, but then I have to DI the LoggerContext into all my classes.

Comment: I found a solution in https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-programmatic-config#configurationfactory. With a custom ConfigurationFactory Spring uses your custom config instead of its default.